# Hmisc package acting weird numeric =/= character

Tags: r, character, numeric

I'm trying to overlay errorbars on top of barcharts and that's working fine, except that the errorbars calculate themselves, so any missing x-values break the plot. as you can see here:
http://flyordie.sin.khk.be/r/asnumeric.PNG

When i change my x-values to characters (as.character(xvalues)) the following happens:
http://flyordie.sin.khk.be/r/ascharacter.PNG

The x and y axis change places. What can I do about this? Because I can't think of anything else.

To reproduce a similar problem, here are 2 scripts

normal

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
y <- x + rnorm(10)
delta <- runif(10)
errbar( x, y, y + delta, y - delta )
```

characters

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
y <- x + rnorm(10)
delta <- runif(10)
errbar( as.character(x), y, y + delta, y - delta )
```

Kind regards 
Sir Ksilem

Comment: can you add a toy example that reproduces your problem? I can't really guess what you mean with missing x-values that woul require you using "as character" to be able to plot...

Comment: Just a second, I'm uploading the dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotting horizontal error bars is the intended behavior for the `errbar()` function when the `x` argument is a factor or character variable, as opposed to numeric.  When you say that missing `x` values break your plot, I interpret you to mean break the lines connecting the dots.  To plot the error bars without breaking the lines, I would simply remove the observations with missing `x` values:

```
require(Hmisc)

## Your example data
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
y <- x + rnorm(10)
delta <- runif(10)

## Make some data vanish
x[c(5,6)] <- NA

## Create an index for non-missing observations in `x`
i <- which(!is.na(x))

errbar(x[i], y[i], y[i] + delta[i], y[i] - delta[i], type = "b")
```

**Edit**
Per your comment below, if platenames is just intended to be your x-axis tick mark labels, then how about the following?

```
require(Hmisc)

## Your example data
set.seed(1)
# `x` should not contain missing values, and is not your platenames vector
x <- 1:10 
y <- x + rnorm(10)
delta <- runif(10)
# xticks represents your platenames vector with missing values
xticks <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, 7, 8, 9, 10)

errbar(x, y, y + delta, y - delta, type = "b")
axis(1, at = xticks, labels = xticks)
```

However, to me  it is confusing as to why you would have observations with missing x-axis tick marks.  As Andrie suggests, perhaps you can clarify why some platenames are missing, and whether platenames are actually supposed to be your x-values, or whether they are just labels.  If they are just labels, perhaps you want to add the labels to the margin with `mtext()`:

```
errbar(x, y, y + delta, y - delta, type = "b")
mtext(text = xticks, side = 3, line = 2, at = xticks)
```

Adjust `side` and `line` per `?mtext` to move the labels around.

Comment: but the x-values are just the platenames. I can't help it if they use some plates and some not.

Comment: @sir ksilem, We have given you a lot of help, both here and on the R chat room.  It is still not obvious what your problem is, or what your expected results are.  If you want a resolution to this question, please spend a bit more time in refining your original question and provide a reproducible example.  You keep talking about missing x-values, but what does "missing" mean?  NA? NULL?  Something else?  What is the problem with the first graph you showed.  What would you like it to be?  Be more specific and then we can possibly help you.

Comment: @Sir Ksilem, Does the platenames vector represent labels for the `x` variable, and not the values of the `x` variable?  If so, does using `mtext()` in my edit above get you closer to what you are after?

Comment: I thank you all for your help, but it's not necesary anmore. I solved the problem by using normal lineplots. The problem is it's hard for me to explain the problem.